# Display Both original price and custom price at manual order creation for customer

Tags: magento-1.9, price, custom-options, custom-prices

After entering the custom price at the stage of admin create manual order, the products original price removed when entering the custom price, I need both an original price and custom price. how to display original price near the custom price.

> Note: Checkout takes custom price, An original price needs to display.

[image]
[image]

> Note : original price: $500 should display for my reference

How can i display both custom price and original price of products at the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will require to rewrite **app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\create\items\grid.phtml** file. Once you rewrite this file to your module. find below code in the file.

```
<?php $_isCustomPrice = $this->usedCustomPriceForItem($_item) ?>
<?php if($_tier = $this->getTierHtml($_item)): ?>
<div id="item_tier_block_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"<?php if ($_isCustomPrice): ?> style="display:none"<?php endif; ?>>
    <a href="#" onclick="$('item_tier_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>').toggle();return false;"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Tier Pricing') ?></a>
    <div style="display:none" id="item_tier_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"><?php echo $_tier ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($this->canApplyCustomPrice($_item)): ?>
<div class="nobr">
<input type="checkbox" id="item_use_custom_price_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"<?php if ($_isCustomPrice): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="order.toggleCustomPrice(this, 'item_custom_price_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>', 'item_tier_block_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>');"/>
<label class="normal" for="item_use_custom_price_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Custom Price') ?>*</label>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<input id="item_custom_price_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="item[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][custom_price]" value="<?php echo sprintf("%.2f", $this->getOriginalEditablePrice($_item))?>"<?php if (!$_isCustomPrice): ?> style="display:none" disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> class="input-text item-price"/>
```

And add below lines after above code.

```
<br>
<span><?php echo $this->__("Original Price: ") . $this->formatPrice($_item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice()); ?></span>
```

It will show you product's original price like below.
[image]

Comment: Perfectly working,

Comment: how can I give a bulk discount for total order value after manual order created? A discount like an amount and percentage wise?

Comment: Sorry but I dont have idea bout that @Rathinam

Comment: Anyone help me, how can i give each product discount(Discount % display ) while creating manual order.